# Labels wrapping input checkbox

Tags: javascript

Generally, I like this style of label and input:

```
<label><input type="checkbox"> Click me!</label>
```

Then I can click both the box and the label. But I toyed with creating things this way:

```
let lab = document.createElement('label');
let cb = document.createElement('input');
cb.type = "checkbox";
lab.appendChild(cb);
```

There is where I got stuck. If I use `lab.innerText="anything"` the checkbox goes away. It's that or put the label before or after the checkbox and then you can't click on the label to change the checkbox. I may be screwing up the HTML. I'm not sure. In the end, I had to use `lab.innerHTML` to add the checkbox. That works, but I know it's not proper. Then I could use `lab.querySelector` to get the checkbox and attach an `onclick` event.

There's got to be a better way.

Comment: Surely you can just append a text node before the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is YES to my comment!

We can insert a text node before the checkbox is inserted.

Thankfully there is a shortcut to inserting a text node, which is just inserting a string with `append`:

```js
let lab = document.createElement('label');

let cb = document.createElement('input');

cb.type = "checkbox";

lab.append("label here");

lab.appendChild(cb);

document.body.appendChild(lab);
```